# How to create sbt task that passes arguments to "run"

Tags: sbt

I would like to create an sbt task, that would be equivalent to `run -Dfoo=bar`. (in case you have never used it, `-D` just injects a configuration override). How should that be done?

In case it matters, only sbt 13.7 and up...

Answer (score 1):

I think you're after [Input Tasks](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Input-Tasks.html), I've never used them before but I'm pretty sure that'll give you everything and more for what you're after.